# Executing test from another test in google test framework

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googletest

Let's say I have two tests in the same testcase: writeTest and readTest

```
TEST_F(testcase, writeTest)
{
  ASSERT_EQ(OK, write_something();
} 

TEST_F(testcase, readTest)
{
  ASSERT_EQ(OK, write_something();
  ASSERT_EQ(OK, read_something();
}
```

My question is, can I execute writeTest from readTest? 
To read something there must be something written. So I want to execute the writeTest (while being in test code of readTest) rather than repeating the codes of writeTest?

This is specially important when there is huge line of code in the writeTest.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a need for your first test case at all. If you write something, how will you know it has worked without reading it afterwards?

First thing you have to ask yourself is, "What is the purpose of my test?"

For example.

Purpose: Write something which should return an error. 
Now it more important check the return error instead of verifying.

Purpose: Write a positive test case
Now its important to test that what you have written can also be read.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: Well in my opinion he is asking the wrong question. This is a typical question from someone new to test automation.